# Statistics - Finding Percentage Utilization

Tags: statistics, percentages, data-analysis

I've been stuck with this question for weeks. There's no answer/working steps for this question. Any help would be appreciated.

If there are 400 spaces in the car park, and it is open from 8:00 AM - 8:00 PM, calculate (or estimate) its percentage utilization.

[Link to data/statistics related to the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04md7.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $400$ spaces, each available for $12$ hours, that gives you $4800$ possible hours of cars parked.  Looking at the data, you could use the midpoint of each time range as being representative of how long cars are parked.  So for example for the range $0$ to $1$ hour , there are $452$ cars, we estimate that they stay for an average of $0.5$ hours each.  This uses up $452\cdot(0.5) = 226$ hours of parking time.  Do the same for the other time ranges (e.g., $737\cdot(1.5)$ and so on) to get a total of how much car time is used.  Then compare to $4800$ total possible car-hours to get your percentage utilization.

Comment: How is it that the midpoint can be used as a representative for how long the cars are parked? Why not use the highest possible value under a class? Meaning, if there are 737 cars parked between 1 and 2 hours, why choose 1.5 (midpoint) instead of 2 (maximum hour for that class)?

Comment: @brdn  You could do that too.  Or you could make a separate calculation with each of the the upper and lower values of the time ranges, and thereby get upper and lower bounds for usage.  It really depends on what kind of estimate you want.  But by taking the midpoint, some of the high and low values will tend to even out.